# How is this approximation made?

Tags: real-analysis

On page IX and X of the preface of Petr Mandl Analytical treatment of one dimensional Markov Processes one finds

[image]

[image]

I tried to approximate the expression

\begin{align}
\lambda_+ &= \frac{1}{2p} \bigg[ \exp\bigg\{ h \bigg(\frac{p}{q}\bigg)^z\bigg\} + \sqrt{\exp\bigg\{ 2h \bigg(\frac{p}{q}\bigg)^z\bigg\} - 4pq} \bigg]\\
& =  \frac{1}{2p} \bigg[ 1 +  h \bigg(\frac{p}{q}\bigg)^z + O\bigg(\bigg(\frac{p}{q}\bigg)^z\bigg) + \sqrt{1 + O\bigg(\bigg(\frac{p}{q}\bigg)^z\bigg) - 4pq} \bigg]\\
& =  \frac{1}{2p} \bigg[ 1 +1 - 2pq + O\bigg(\bigg(\frac{p}{q}\bigg)^z\bigg) \bigg]\\
& = \frac{1 - pq}{p} +  O\bigg(\bigg(\frac{p}{q}\bigg)^z\bigg) 
\end{align}

But this is not going very well...

Any ideas on how this is done?

Comment: @NormalHuman I don't understand what you mean. Is this an automatic comment or did you read something that was not in order. If it was an authomatic comment what have I done to trigger it? best!